# Graph Theory Problem (Algorithms)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

[image]

I'm having difficulty in approaching this problem and coming up with a solution. I'm not sure where to start in answering this question.

Comment: I would suggest drawing a small graph, and then try to follow the algorithm step by step. That way it is clearer what the algorithm does. Hint: Can an element in S share an edge with another element in S?

Comment: You should type in the question instead of posting an image. An image takes longer to download, is more difficult to view on small screens, and is not searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $S$ is going to be an independent set of vertices. Proof: take $s_1,s_2\in S$. Suppose without loss of generality that $s_1$ was added before $s_2$. then at the point in which $s_2$ was added, all of the neighbours of $s_1$ that had been in $R$ had already been eliminated, thus there is no edge between $s_1$ and $s_2$.